# Understand arrow function based on event

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, keypress, arrow-functions

I have the following codes:

```
class Autocomplete {
  constructor(ele, options) {
    this.ele = ele;
    this.options = options;
    this.input = this.ele.querySelector('.input');
    // with keyup we want to fire it right away
    // this.input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => this.display(e);
  }
}
```

The `display` function will then display the user's input onto the page. However, I wonder what the difference is between these 3 functions:

1)

```
this.input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => this.display(e));
```

2. 

```
this.input.addEventListener('keyup', this.display);
```

3. 

```
this.input.addEventListener('keyup', () => this.display());
```

Only function 1 and 2 work, and to my understanding, function 1 will put `e` as argument into the `display` function whereas function 2 will execute immediately on `keyup`. However, for 3, why does it not work, because I thought the `e` argument is passed in implicitly by the DOM API?

Out of the first 2 functions, which one is more performant and why?

Answer (score 1):

Arrow function is not bound to the class where it is declared when it is called, you should use function only if you want to use the this in the function because in the arrow function, it's the global this that is get called

Comment: Huh? `this` in the arrow function will be the class instance. I'm not sure what you meant here

Comment: This in the arrow function is the global this.
You will not be able to get the class' variables if you use arrow function

Comment: Take a look at this article https://betterprogramming.pub/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256